# How to display current window to notification bar NOT HIDE in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, notification-bar

I've created one WPF application. It has one window and it's hide on close button. But i want to show it in notification-bar. and when user click on that then windows should display.

Here is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
    aTimer.Interval = 3000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lblProcess.Content = "Test Window"

}

// minimize to system tray when applicaiton is closed
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // setting cancel to true will cancel the close request
    // so the application is not closed
    e.Cancel = true;

    this.Hide();
    //this.Show();

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

I've already read this: [create-popup-toaster-notifications-in-windows-with-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034741/create-popup-toaster-notifications-in-windows-with-net)

And [minimizing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf-not-using-notifyicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700606/minimizing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf-not-using-notifyicon)

[minimizing-closing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265139/minimizing-closing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf)

But didn't get you how can i do this?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimizing/Closing Application to system tray using WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265139/minimizing-closing-application-to-system-tray-using-wpf)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, Have to read my question? Please read it first. I want to show this in notification

Comment: Yes, I read your question. The posts you linked yourself contain all the info you need. If you have further questions to the answers you already read - you can add a comment (when you have enough reputation) to the original answer and ask for clarification. Since you didn't include the required [MCVE] we can't help you any further than you already managed to get.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, It's about to hide window, that i did, **I WANT IN NOTIFICATION**

Comment: check this: https://ebbypeter.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/minimize-a-wpf-application-to-system-tray-in-c/

Comment: @Motivated, Thanks for the link

Comment: @user6689472 Then you should clarify your question. "I WANT IN NOTIFICATION" - what do you want in the notification? Your code simply contains a `ListProcesses();`. What is it you want to show? "But i want to show it in notification-bar.". Rephrase your question to make sense and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Dear @ManfredRadlwimmer if you read the question carefully then must read this line **. It has one window and it's hide on close button. But i want to show it in notification-bar.** this is a second sentence of my question.

Comment: *Rephrase your question to make sense and someone might be able to help you* It's make sense if you take a few minutes and read it, instead of just flag it to duplicate or down vote!

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, Are you there? Now do you have any idea?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. The way it is phrased it sounds like you want to show the window in the taskbar (which wouldn't fit, for obvious reasons). I get the part, that you want to hide the window instead of closing it, but you said you already do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done using this code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("D:\\images.ico");
ni.Visible = true;
ni.DoubleClick +=delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
               {
                  this.Show();
                  this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
               };
```